# error getting multiple child values from firebase

Tags: android, arrays, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get multiple child values from my RealTime Database and store it in an String array, the method i'm using is shown below:-

```
 dbRef.child(REQUESTED_NODE).child(REQUESTED_PRODUCT).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                SearchKeywords item = postSnapshot.getValue(SearchKeywords.class);

                SearchKeys.add(String.valueOf(item));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

the problem is what it is getting. It is not showing the required text and instead shows something which I'm not sure what it is. Below is what it is returning.

> I/Keywords: [com.strease.user.strease.SearchKeywords@3b2d439, com.strease.user.strease.SearchKeywords@ce3ea7e, com.strease.user.strease.SearchKeywords@9f16bdf, com.strease.user.strease.SearchKeywords@823102c, com.strease.user.strease.SearchKeywords@3e37af5, com.strease.user.strease.SearchKeywords@5d0308a, com.strease.user.strease.SearchKeywords@d2ae6fb, com.strease.user.strease.SearchKeywords@ec70318, com.strease.user.strease.SearchKeywords@a3dd171, com.strease.user.strease.SearchKeywords@88cb56, com.strease.user.strease.SearchKeywords@2b6f7d7, com.strease.user.strease.SearchKeywords@eb538c4, com.strease.user.strease.SearchKeywords@60d13ad, com.strease.user.strease.SearchKeywords@45e46e2, com.strease.user.strease.SearchKeywords@a893a73, com.strease.user.strease.SearchKeywords@42f1d30, com.strease.user.strease.SearchKeywords@6143da9

Comment: This result depends on your `SearchKeywords` class (which doesn't seem to have a `toString` method) and the JSON at `REQUESTED_NODE/REQUESTED_PRODUCT`. Please add both to your question. You can get the JSON by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Please add your database structure, the content of your `SearchKeywords` class and the way you printing those items and please also responde with @AlexMamo